# Matlab Curve Fitting via Optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization, curve-fitting, minimization

I have tried to follow [this tutorial](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/example-curve-fitting-via-optimization.html) to fit a curve to my [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilzpps75pc8r103/atomicclockgpsworld.txt?dl=0). The equation for the curve should be

```
f(t) = log10((wpmcoeff./(t.^2)) + 
       ((1.038+3.*log(2.*pi.*1e6.*t)).*fpmcoeff./(t.^2))+(wfmcoeff./t) + 
       (ffmcoeff)+(rwfmcoeff.*t)).
```

I have created the following code:

```
clock='atomicclockgpsworld.txt';
data=importdata(clock);

carrier=10e6;

sig=data(:,2);
t=data(:,1);
sigsq=log10(sig.^2);
fun = @(coeff)sseval(coeff,t,sigsq);
x0 = rand(5,1);
bestx = fminsearch(fun,x0);
wpmcoeff = bestx(1);
fpmcoeff = bestx(2);
wfmcoeff = bestx(3);
ffmcoeff = bestx(4);
rwfmcoeff = bestx(5);
yfit=log10((wpmcoeff./(t.^2))+((1.038+3.*log(2.*pi.*1e6.*t)).*fpmcoeff./(t.^2))+(wfmcoeff./t))+(ffmcoeff)+(rwfmcoeff.*t);
semilogx(t,sigsq,'x');
hold on
semilogx(t,yfit);
saveas(gcf,'fit','png');
```

and the corresponding function

```
function sse = sseval(coeff,t,sigsq)
    wpmcoeff = coeff(1);
    fpmcoeff = coeff(2);
    wfmcoeff = coeff(3);
    ffmcoeff = coeff(4);
    rwfmcoeff = coeff(5);
    sse = sum(sigsq - (log10((wpmcoeff./(t.^2))+((1.038+3.*log(2.*pi.*1e6.*t)).*fpmcoeff./(t.^2))+(wfmcoeff./t)+(ffmcoeff)+(rwfmcoeff.*t))));
end
```

But the fit produced is horrible (my y data should vary between approximately -20 to -22 but the fit produces a curve that reaches 1e59!). Can anyone suggest where I may be going wrong?

Current output vs data:

[image: Link to the plot that is created.]

Answer (score 3):

In your function `sseval` the function is different then the one in your first script. In the function you take the `log10` of the whole equation, while in the script `log10` stops at `(wfmcoeff./t)`:

first script:

```
log10((wpmcoeff./(t.^2))+((1.038+3.*log(2.*pi.*1e6.*t)).*fpmcoeff./(t.^2))+(wfmcoeff./t))+(ffmcoeff)+(rwfmcoeff.*t)
```

function:

```
log10((wpmcoeff./(t.^2))+((1.038+3.*log(2.*pi.*1e6.*t)).*fpmcoeff./(t.^2))+(wfmcoeff./t)+(ffmcoeff)+(rwfmcoeff.*t))
```

A second thing is that you didn't take the square of the difference. So in your function change the last line to

```
sse = sum((sigsq - (log10((wpmcoeff./(t.^2))+((1.038+3.*log(2.*pi.*1e6.*t)).*fpmcoeff./(t.^2))+(wfmcoeff./t))+(ffmcoeff)+(rwfmcoeff.*t))).^2);
```

Note: the fitting is sometimes good, sometimes it's really rubbish, so run the script a couple of times to get a good fitting. After a few times I got the following:

[image]

The parameters found are:

```
wpmcoeff: 10.898483535691309
wfmcoeff: 22.933722400252414
rwfmcoeff: 3.601059651996531e-05
fpmcoeff: -0.324473127267299
ffmcoeff: -21.497862719234053
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ViG! I really appreciate your help! My only issue now is that the whole function was actually supposed to be 'log'ed - I have done this in my code but can't reproduce a fit anywhere near as nice as the one you found.. mine looks like this after several attempts https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyms3zcizy3g937/fit.png?dl=0

Comment: The results I got when I log the whole function are even worse than yours. I don't know why it is that bad now..